# What are non-jQuery objects exactly used for in the framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am new to jQuery.I read on the official website of jQuery that there are two types of objects that it can manage: jQuery objects and non-jQuery objects.

Non-jQuery objects are actually Javascripts objects (native and custom objects).

Here is a jQuery object `var heading = $("h1");`

I still do not understand why the framework considers non-jQuery objects. What are the concrete uses of these objects in the framework?

Are there otherthe methods than iteration methods `$.each()` and `$.map()`?

Here is the link of the website: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
Native Objects are simply objects,
The jQuery objects are jQuery type of class(object) that have 
many functions related to them.

for example, you cant use $.each() on Native js object only for object that you got
by doing something like this: $("html") - which is basically a function who creates
jQuery object.

that pretty much it.